# If variable a is a char array is char* p = &a defined behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory-address

I've always thought that:

```
char a[10];
char* p = &a;
```

Is wrong and that it should be one of the following instead:

```
char a[10];
char* p = a; // OR
char* p = &a[0];
```

I wish I could find the thread here on SO I was reading saying that p = &a; is valid, and it was in regard to the C language, not C++.

I've been thinking, obviously:

```
char* p = new char[10];
char* p1 = &p; // Is wrong
```

But when an array is created as a local in stack space it seems reasonable to my intuition that `a`, `&a`, and `&a[0]` are all the same value/address. I have to say, I've been following mostly C++ and not seen it done this way, which is why when I started to look into C I was quick to call it an error, but I'm sure it's not in C (well verification on that would be appreciated also). I'm just wondering if it's also the case in C++, because as far as I remember in C++ is usually done one of the other two ways and this way (if my imagination isn't playing tricks) seems to done in C.

Edit: This is a really dumb question. My confusion came from the fact that my Visual Studio compiler compiles it in C, but not for C++, so I thought there was a difference in the language in this respect. I won't delete the question because it already has an answer.

Comment: Same address, different types. Your compiler should give you a type mismatch error because p is a pointer to a char, but &a is a pointer to an array of 10 chars.

Comment: @immibis Ohhh, I see. I have my Visual Studio set up for both C and C++, I've just tried it, seems this is another one of those differences between the two languages.

Comment: Consider the following: `struct foo { int x; int y; }; struct foo obj; int *ptr = &obj;`

Comment: What do you mean, difference between the two languages? It's the same in both.

Comment: @melpomene No actually with C it compiles with me, but not C++. Hmm, let me try some other compilers. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: C / C++ compilers are not required to reject invalid programs. Did you get any warnings?

Comment: @melpomene On an online compiler with GCC it indeed says type mismatch. On my Visual Studio compiled strictly in C and with language extensions disabled it compiles fine. In fact someone posted C code as a question on here doing this, and his algorithm worked fine, and no one called him out on it. Strange. I wish I could find that question..

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question is about other than your jumbled recollection of past questions that may or may not exist

Comment: This: *On an online compiler with GCC it indeed says type mismatch. On my Visual Studio compiled strictly in C and with language extensions disabled it compiles fine.*  The 'visual studio' is well known for not properly implementing the C language AND is over a decade behind the current C language definition.  So you have to be very careful about believing what `visual studio` says

Answer (score 5):

```
char a[10];
char* p = &a;
```

is indeed wrong in C.

In particular (all quotes refer to ISO 9899:1999 (C99) and all emphasis is mine):

6.7.8 (Initialization) / 11 says:

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The
>   initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); **the same type
>   constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply**, taking the type of the scalar
>   to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

6.5.16.1 (Simple assignment):

> **Constraints**
>
> 1. One of the following shall hold:
>
>    - the left operand has qualified or unqualified arithmetic type and the right has
>        arithmetic type;
>    - the left operand has a qualified or unqualified version of a structure or union type
>        compatible with the type of the right;
>    - **both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types**,
>        and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the
>        right;
>    - one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a
>        qualified or unqualified version of `void`, and the type pointed to by the left has all
>        the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
>    - the left operand is a pointer and the right is a null pointer constant; or
>    - the left operand has type `_Bool` and the right is a pointer.

Only the bold part applies; we're not using any arithmetic or struct/union types, there's no `void` or `_Bool` and no null pointer constants.

The types in question are `char *` (pointer to `char`) on the left and `char (*)[10]` (pointer to array[10] of `char`) on the right. Compatibility of pointer types is defined as follows:

6.7.5.1 (Pointer declarators) / 2:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and **both shall
>   be pointers to compatible types**.

The pointed-to types are `char` and `char [10]`, respectively.

But now we're stuck. There is 6.2.7 (Compatible type and composite type) / 1:

> Two types have *compatible type* if their types are the same. Additional rules for
>   determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers,
>   in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.5 for declarators.

`char` and `char [10]` are clearly not the same. All the declarator rules for compatible types in 6.7.5 say "*For two pointer types to be compatible ...*",  "*For two array types to be compatible ...*", "*For two function types to be compatible ...*", but there is no way for a non-array type to be compatible with an array type.

Thus the types are not compatible and `char *p = &a` violates a constraint in 6.5.16.1.

5.1.1.3 (Diagnostics):

> **A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message** (identified in
>   an implementation-defined manner) **if a** preprocessing translation unit or **translation unit
>   contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint**, even if the behavior is also explicitly
>   specified as undefined or implementation-defined.

This means a warning or error message is required. If your compiler doesn't produce one, it's not an actual C compiler.

Comment: I'm always amazed at how fast some of you guys can get the correct paragraphs from the standard. Every time I try, I get lost in the document.

Comment: @Pablo Hah. I actually had to deal with a genuine Windows bluescreen + memory dump (followed by a reboot) in the middle of writing that answer.

Comment: Which comment, you mean the answer? I don't understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @Pablo I'm saying I find it funny that you thought it was fast, because to me it felt agonizingly slow waiting for memory to be dumped, waiting for Windows to restart, waiting for the browser to come up again, etc. :-)

Comment: haha, I understand. Even in that time it took you to write the answer, I probably wouldn't have found the correct place anyway.

Comment: "For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified..." Does that rule mean that the two types must have the same const qualification? Doesn't that mean that char* a; const char* const p = a; is wrong according to the rule?

Comment: @Zebrafish The rule for assignment says "*both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right*", which allows the left side to be more qualified than the right.